# Javascript create array of Object property values

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given this Object in Javascript

```
{
  "0": "hello",
  "1": { text: "world" }
}
```

What's the shortest way to create this array from that object?

```
[
  "hello",
  { text: "world" }
]
```

I've seen somebody using `Array.prototype.splice(theObject)` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

**Update:**

1. Order of output needs to be guaranteed
2. `0` and `1` can be any arbitrary string value and the order at property level needs to be maintained in the corresponding array.
3. Needs to work with Node.js 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should maintain the order based on the keys, including where keys have more than one digit

```js
const test = {
  "0": "hello",
  "3": "three",
  "1": { text: "world" },
  "2": "two",
  "11": "eleven",
}

const transform = obj => Object.keys(obj)
  .sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) > parseInt(b) ? 1 : -1)
  .map(key => obj[key])
  
 console.dir(transform(test))
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use Object.values:

```js
console.log(Object.values({
  "0": "hello",
  "1": { text: "world" }
}));
```

Comment: This would work but it cannot guarantee that `"hello"` will be the first value in the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, please see me updated question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that the original keys of the object correspond to the positions in the resulting array, you can't rely on `Object.values()` or a `for ... in` loop. You can use `Object.keys()` and sort that array.

```
var keys = Object.keys(yourObject);
keys.sort();
var array = keys.map(key => yourObject[key]);
```

Now understand that the call to `.sort()` can include a comparator function to impose any ordering desired on the original object keys. The sample in the OP is very simple, and the above would work. However more complicated keys might require a custom comparator.

Comment: I believe this may give an incorrect order if the keys went into more than one digit, as it'd sort them in what it believed to be alphabetical order

Comment: @OliverRadini yes, it depends on the keys; the OP didn't go into much detail. The point is that the `.sort()` can explicitly impose any ordering desired. I'll extend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let src = {
  "0": "hello",
  "1": {
    text: "world"
  }
}

let res = [src].map(it => [it['0'], it['1']])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using for..in loop like this:

```
let obj = {
  "0": "hello",
  "1": { text: "world" }
   }
  let result = []
  for(var value in obj){
     result.push(obj[value])
   }
```